# Error #2101 Don't understand why

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

So I've got a AS3 code that send a variable to a PHP page.

Here's my AS3 code :

```
function sendData(evt:Event):void {
    // Create a new URLRequest instance sending data to "ascom01.php"
    var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("http://www/***/***/script.php");

    // Send data using the POST method
    urlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 

// The data property of the request is set to the
    // URLVariables instance (myVariables) to send to the PHP file.
    // Note: myVariables stored the variable (e.g. candidate)
    var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 

    urlVars.theport = mySharedObject.data.theCity;
    trace(urlVars.theport);
    urlReq.data = urlVars;  
    trace(urlReq.data);

    // Create a new instance of the URLLoader class to work with.
    // URLLoader.load( ) method should be used when we need the 
    // sent variables returned back to Flash ActionScript.

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (urlReq); 
    //specify dataFormat property of the URLLoader to be "VARIABLES"
    //This ensure that the variables loaded into Flash with the same variable names
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES; 

    //Load the PHP file by using URLRequest

    loader.load(urlReq); 
    //Listen when the loading of data COMPLETE
    //Call the loadComplete function when the loading COMPLETE
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
}
```

So the `trace(urlReq.data);` output : `theport=Thio`

In my php page I've got :

```
$theport = $_POST['theport'];
```

But each time the function sendData is triggered in my AS3, I've got this error :

```
Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
    at flash.net::URLVariables()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

So the loadComplete is not called as there is this problem before. Any idea what could cause this ?

Thx a lot,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500974/2101-the-string-passed-to-urlvariables-decode-must-be-a-url-encoded-query-st

Comment: show your onComplete method.  Most likely what you're returning form PHP isn't a url encoded string (eg. `"var=value&var2=value2&var3=val3"`)